# How to debug an iOS app that does not make it past launch for certain users?

Tags: ios, xcode, crittercism

I have hundreds of people using my app, but a handful are reporting that the app does not make it past the black launch screen (it immediately closes, before entering into my app). I'm using `Crittercism` but it's not even getting far enough to catch any exception, which makes it sound like a springboard / backboard problem.

Here's what I've asked the users to do:

1. Reinstall the app
2. Delete some apps (to free some space)
3. Restart the device

None of the above worked. I'm completely at a loss as to what's wrong. The app is in the AppStore and works fine for most users. Furthermore, I can't find anything unique about these users (they're using recent versions of iOS with fairly modern hardware).

Answer (score 0):

`Crittercism` doesn't show anything, because after the crash - log will be send only at the next launch, so if user doesn't open your app anymore (or can't do it, because he has constant crash).
I advice your to try next ideas:

- Do use use keychain or store smth there? It's not cleared after uninstall
- Maybe your data is backed up in icloud
- Did it begin with the new iOs version (9.0 for example)
- Maybe it's some cache problem after installing one version on another,
- Can it be the problem of different timezones
- Can it be a crash with local settings
- If you have feedback with users with crash - contact them and ask about device, iOs version and other
- your have crash sections in your `itunesconnect` profile, maybe there you'll get some information

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have no keychain integration, no icloud, it doesn't appear to be an iOS version problem, and this is happening to people on a fresh install for the very first time on the device so it's not cache problems. Could you expand on the local settings and timezones? What kind of problems could these be?

Comment: @ZaneClaes I mean, that your users can be for example in Tokyo, New-York, London and timezone is different - you can possibly have some bug issue with NSDate or NSDateFormatter or NSCalendar and so on. Local - is language setting, it can be en, en-us, ru and be a little different if you have localization or local dependecy